# Eclipse Luna: Remove Vertical Ruler with PyDev plugin

Tags: python, eclipse

I just upgraded from Eclipse Kepler to Luna. I'm coding in Python using the PyDev plugin. Since upgrading, this vertical bar appeared on the right hand side of the text area. I understand that some people find this feature useful, but I find it extremely distracting. I've looked again and again, but I can't figure out a way to remove it. Is there any such way? If not, is there some sort of "hack" that could make it invisible. Thanks!